# How do I add an extra item in my drop down list,I am using datatable as datasource

Tags: c#, .net

I am using database table as data source for my dropdown list. How do I add an extra item in my dropdown list for example "select state".

currently my code is:

```
dropdownlist1.datasource=dt;
dropdownlist1.datavaluefield="countryid";
dropdownlist1.datatextfield="countryname";
```

dt is a datatable , "countryid" & "countryname" are columns

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do some thing like

```
dropdownlist1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select country", "0"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this

```
dropdownlist1.DataSource = dt;
dropdownlist1.DataTextField = "countryname";
dropdownlist1.DataValueField = "countryid";
dropdownlist1.DataBind();
dropdownlist1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("select state", "0"));
```